# OCAPI: using expand parameters returns status code 400

Tags: rest-api, api, commerce-cloud, b2b-commerce

Using the Coupon resource of the Data API, I am trying to get the count of the total codes and redemptions for a specific coupon. Unfortunately, when I use expand parameters `redemption_count` and `total_codes_count`, I get back for example error 400 - "The expand value 'redemption_count' is invalid.".

Tested URLs:

- /coupons/aCoupon?expand=redemption_count
- /coupons/aCoupon?expand=total_codes_count
- /coupons/aCoupon?expand=(redemption_count)
- /coupons/aCoupon?expand=(total_codes_count)
- /coupons/aCoupon?expand=(redemption_count, total_codes_count)

I even tried the CouponSearch resource, to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation states to use 'stats' to get those three values.

Please try: /coupons/aCoupon?expand=stats